# Does Firefox support Javascript in XHTML pages?

Tags: javascript, xml, firefox, xhtml

I need to serve XHTML pages that include Javascript. My problem is that Firefox (3.5.7) seems to ignore the Javascript. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>My Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.write("Hello world!");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I save this as `test.html`, Firefox displays this correctly. If I save this as `test.xml`, Firefox displays a blank page. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Just don't use document.write().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.write` does not work but setting `innerHTML` is still working. Just remember that whatever you set in there must be well-formed.

This means that you can use jQuery to add new element/set html to any element.

I have a small library used for this. It work quite a bit.

```
function IsXHTML() {
    if (document.doctype == null)
        return false;

    var vPublic = document.doctype.publicId.replace(/^.*(.html).*$/i, '$1').toLowerCase();
    var vSystem = document.doctype.systemId.replace(/^.*(.html).*$/i, '$1').toLowerCase();
    return (vPublic == 'xhtml')
        && (vSystem == 'xhtml');
};

function XHTMLDocWrite($Str, $Element) {
    if ($Str == null)
        return;

    var vIsMozilla = !window.opera && !/Apple/.test(navigator.vendor);
    var vIsOpera   =  window.opera;

    // Make sure &s are formatted properly
    if (!vIsOpera)
         $Str = $Str.replace(/&(?![#a-z0-9]+;)/g, "&amp;");
    else $Str = $Str.replace(/&(?![#a-z0-9]+;)/g, "&");

    // - Mozilla assumes that everything in XHTML, innerHTML is actually XHTML
    // - Opera and Safari assume that it's XML
    if ( !vIsMozilla )
        $Str = $Str.replace(/(<[a-z]+)/g, "$1 xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'");

    // The HTML needs to be within a XHTML element
    var vDiv = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml","div");
    vDiv.innerHTML = $Str;

    if ($Element == null) {
        // Find the last element in the document
        var vLastElmt = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
        vLastElmt = vLastElmt[vLastElmt.length - 1];
        $Element = vLastElmt;
    }

    // Add all the nodes in that position
    var vNodes = vDiv.childNodes;
    while (vNodes.length)
        $Element.parentNode.appendChild( vNodes[0] );
};

function UseXHTMLDocWrite($IsForced) {
    if (!IsXHTML() && !$IsForced)
        return;
    if (document.write == XHTMLDocWrite)
        return;

    document.write = XHTMLDocWrite;
};
```

You run `UseXHTMLDocWrite` so that `document.write` will be replaced with `XHTMLDocWrite` if needed.

This will simply add content to the last added element. However, it does not work with nested element.

NOTE: I modify the code of `XHTMLDocWrite` from the code I got from some where on the Internet and cannot seems to find it anymore. So sorry I can't credit him.

Hope this helps.

Comment: AWESOME. But remember to wrap your script in CDATA if you include it as-is on your page, escpecially if it's for XHTML.

Answer (score 7):

From http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/2004/xhtml-faq#docwrite

> **Does document.write work in XHTML?**
>
> No. Because of the way XML is defined, it is not possible to do tricks like this, where markup is generated by scripting while the parser is still parsing the markup.
>
> You can still achieve the same effects, but you have to do it by using the DOM to add and delete elements.

Comment: OMG. Does this mean that many (most?) Javascript libraries out there will simply not work?

Comment: I'd hope that most JavaScript libraries wouldn't use document.write. It's nasty.

Comment: Important second part to this answer: **That doesn't mean you can't use JavaScript with XHTML** It just means you can't use `document.write`. Instead, as the W3C quote says, once the page is loaded you can use DOM manipulation to add/modify content. It's a bit of a pain writing JavaScript within the XHTML file itself; you're best of locating it in a separate JavaScript file and using the `src` attribute of the `script` tag to bring it in.